# Searching with dynamic field name in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, dynamic, field

I have a situation where records in Mongo DB are like :

```
{
"_id" : "xxxx",
"_class" : "xxxx",
"orgId" : xxx,
"targetKeyToOrgIdMap" : {
    "46784_56139542ecaa34c13ba9e314" : 46784,
    "47530_562f1bc5fc1c1831d38d1900" : 47530,
    "700004280_56c18369fc1cde1e2a017afc" : 700004280


   },
}
```

I have to find out the records where child nodes of **targetKeyToOrgIdMap** has  a particular set of values. That means, I know what the value is going to be there in the record in **"46784_56139542ecaa34c13ba9e314" : 46784** part. And the field name is variable, its combination of the value and some random string.

In above example, I have 46784, and I need to find all the records which have 46784 in that respective field.

Is there any way I can fire some regex or something like that or by using any other mean where I would get the records which has the value I need in the child nodes of the field targetKeyToOrgIdMap.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not possible using the `find()` method, perhaps with `mapReduce`. You may need to consider changing your schema to make `targetKeyToOrgIdMap` an array of objects with key and value properties, which is easier to query: `"targetKeyToOrgIdMap" : [ { "id":     "46784_56139542ecaa34c13ba9e314", "value" : 46784 }, {
"id": "47530_562f1bc5fc1c1831d38d1900", "value": 47530 } ]`

Comment: changing schema won't be possible. I have to maybe skip this or something ... Thanks @chridam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use MongoDB's `$where` like this:

```
db.myCollection.find( { $where: function() { 
  for (var key in obj.targetKeyToOrgIdMap) {
    if (obj.targetKeyToOrgIdMap[key] == 46784){
      return true;
    }
  }
}}).each { obj ->
  println obj
}
```

But be aware that this will require a full table scan where the function is executed for each document. See [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/).

Comment: That does look promising. Pardon my ignorance here, I'm very new to MongoDB; how can I get the records ?
The query is executed successfully but there were no records to show. I tried doing few things like return key / return {} but didnt work. Could you maybe provide me some help on that ?

Comment: Depending on the database driver you use the `find` will probably return a database cursor with which you access the results. Which driver do you use?

Comment: I use gmongo with groovy.

Comment: In this case you can use `.each {}` on the result of `find`, see my updated answer. The query itself is probably no valid Groovy though (never used it personally so far).

Comment: Thanks @Erik. I will transform it to match groovy formatting rules.